# Is there any issue using Salesforce with a BlackBerry mobile

Tags: mobile, blackberry

Actually some of our clients are complaining that they are not able to Approve or Reject using  email through their Blackberry mobile.

Approval or Rejection is working fine for iPhone, iPad and other mobile devices except Blackberry.

I am not getting any clue can someone put light on it.

Comment: I have a nearly 3 yr old Blackberry Curve 8530. I use Mobile Lite with it in Dev Orgs. I vaguely recall attempting to do an approval with it from my Dev Org once without success. Email support is very good on the Blackberry, but the Browser is incredibly ancient. I strongly suspect the browser is probably the issue your Blackberry clients are having. Are your clients using full SF Mobile or Mobile Lite and which BBerrys are they using?